# How do I know what decompression algorithms are compiled-in into the linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, proc, compression, initramfs, sysfs

If `/proc/config.gz` is unavailable, how do I know what decompression algorithms the running kernel is capable of using on a compressed `cpio` `initramfs`?

Is the `gzip` algorithm always available, even when `CONFIG_DECOMPRESS_GZIP` is not `y` when building the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compression algorithms are declared in [`lib/decompress.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/decompress.c). Gzip is defined in [`lib/decompress_inflate.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/decompress_inflate.c) and doesn't get any special status; it'll only be there if `CONFIG_DECOMPRESS_GZIP` is `y` when the kernel is compiled.

The list of available compression algorithms is the [`compressed_formats`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/decompress.c?v=3.14#L45) structure. Since it's defined as `static`, it isn't available in other source files. The only function that uses it is thus the `decompress_method` function in `lib/decompress.c` itself. So the only way to get a kernel to use the table of supported algorithms is to attempt to decompress something that starts with the appropriate two-byte magic sequence, and see if that function returns the algorithm name.

You can tell which decompression functions are supported by searching the list of kernel symbols (`/proc/kallsyms`). The functions aren't identified as such, so you'll need to bake in the list of symbol names.

```
</proc/kallsyms cut -d " " -f 3 |
grep -xF -e gunzip -e bzip2 -e unlzma -e unxz -e unlzo -e unlz4
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk for the win:

```
samveen@x230:~ $ awk '/^name/{n=$3}/^type/{if($3=="compression"){print n}}' </proc/crypto 
lz4
lzo-rle
lzo
deflate
compress_null
```

**Explaination**:

Print the kernel algorithms from `/proc/crypto` flagged as `type` `compression`.

Note: `/proc` is **always** available in **every** `linux` kernel based environment, be it via a `initrd` or containers (like `docker`), so this method should work for all recent kernels

**Caveat Emptor**:

- As pointed out in the comments, this does seem to miss `xz`, even for my env.
- As per [this thread](https://linux-kernel.vger.kernel.narkive.com/ugK7lCCj/crypto-add-alg-type-to-proc-crypto-output) in the kernel mailing list, this test is only available kernel 2.6 onwards.
- Lastly, as pointed out in the comments, if the kernel build doesn't include algorithms under crypto, you get exactly what's included there. For example, [v2.6](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.0/source/crypto) implemented just `deflate`, while [v3.18.140](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18.140/source/crypto) had `deflate` and `lz4`.

Comment: Nice! I love `awk`, but this appears to miss a lot of methods that the `/proc/kallsyms` method from Gilles shows. (lza, lzma, xz). Also, on old (2.6 series) kernels, popular when asked, `/proc/crypto` had no compression algorithms, so I'm not sure this is an answer to the exact question asked, about what compressions were usable with initramfs on the current kernel.

Comment: `/proc` is _not_ always available in containers like docker: If these are getting stripped down to the minimum for security reasons, it may have been omitted deliberately.

Comment: @Juergen Anything in a docker container will also **never** interact with the compression algorithms in the kernel, so there is never any need to check for kernel compression algorithms inside a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to know your compression type by going into the directory sys/power/tuxonice/compression there u will a file named algorithm go into it it will have the decompression type in it for me it was written lzo.

Comment: `/sys/power/tuxonice` does not exist on a typical Linux.